# Setting up Gitolite to have more than 1 admin?

Tags: gitolite

I have a server with gitolite already set up.

I manage the gitolite using a remote machine that has the clone of the gitolite admin.

i.e, In remote machine, I did

> ```
> git clone git@gitserveraddr:gitolite-admin.git
> ```

and manage the users and repos from there.

Now, we would like to have another person in different machine to be able to be the "admin" too. How can I do this?

I tried to add his rsa key into the /home/git/ in the gitserver and run
    gitolite setup -pk Git-Admin.pub his-key.pub
where Git-Admin.pub is the original admin's computer rsa key.
and his-key.pub is the new admin

It did not work.  The original admin is still fine, but the new admin is not working (cannot do git clone git@gitserveraddr:gitolite-admin.git)

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you want to add multiple keys to the same admin account? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733699/gitolite-one-user-many-keys-different-usernames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to modify the [`conf/gitolite.conf`](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#the-special-gitolite-admin-repo) file in order to add a new username as having the right (`RW+`) to read/write to that repo.

```
repo gitolite-admin
   RW+ = alice <newAdmin>
```

You would push as well a new `keydir/<newAdmin.pub>`, allowing `newAdmin` to be able to clone/pull/push `gitolite-admin`.

No need for any "setup".
No need to add multiple keys for the same admin account: it is best to clearly identify and separate each admin account, with their own respective set of ssh public/private keys that each account is in charge of managing (and of keeping their private ssh keys... private).